# php comparison of values in two radio buttons

Tags: php, html

this is one radio button set

```
<input type="radio" name="image" id="100" value="a"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="100" value="b"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="100" value="c"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="200" value="d"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="200" value="e"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="300" value="f"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="300" value="g"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" id="400" value="h"/>
```

and so on...

and this is another radio button set

```
<input type="radio" name="number" value="100"/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="200"/>200
<input type="radio" name="number" value="300"/>300
<input type="radio" name="number" value="400"/>400
<input type="radio" name="number" value="500"/>500
<input type="radio" name="number" value="600"/>600
```

my question is how can i compare value of one with value="100" to other with id="100" in php

there is a comparison i want to make but for the field with id = 100 i have values as abcd.. so i cant assign it value = 100 cuz i m saving it in database
means..
there are other fields with id=100 but their values shall be diffrent otherwise i m not able to identify them after they are send to databse
still i have to do comparison of both.. and that too serverside
so what are my options?

more detailed explanation....
there are two sets of radio buttons..
in one set there are values..
and in other sets there are images related to those values..
when user clicks set of value... and user click on set of images
so php shall match that image to the value.. if user clicked on 100 as value and later he clicks on an image under the id 200
database shall not allow it to enter and gave him some error

Comment: `other fields with id=100`? ids must be unique across the entire document. if you have duplicate ids, you have an invalid document and will have undefined things occuring.

Comment: @marcB actually i do have duplicate id's but it is working good.. no problem with code..

Comment: @user2057047 Yet. You will have problems with the code. Especially when using javascript's `getElementById` (notice how it's not `getElementsById`). Please switch to using duplicate class names, not duplicate IDs

Comment: no, it's not working "good". it's working BY CHANCE.

Comment: How do you want to compare them.

Comment: It's is also best practice to use class names when your id is no longer unique.

Comment: @marcB i ll change it to classes then.. what about this answer?? the duplicate case is for diffrent set of buttons..

Comment: @ColinMorelli i ll change it to classes then.. what about this answer?? the duplicate case is for diffrent set of buttons..

Comment: @TimLieberman i ll change it to classes then.. what about this answer?? the duplicate case is for diffrent set of buttons..

Comment: HTML ids are not sent across when you submit a form. only the name/value attributes. PHP will NEVER see those ids come back.

Comment: @MarcB this i already know hence i raised a question.. :(

Comment: @user2057047: why not put the "100" into the name, like "image_100"?

Comment: Whats the purpose for comparing. Is there a right or wrong answer or are you just wanting to group the value to image values?

Comment: @TimLieberman more detailed explanation.... there are two sets of radio buttons.. in one set there are values.. and in other sets there are images related to those values.. when user clicks set of value... and user click on set of images so php shall match that image to the value.. if user clicked on 100 as value and later he clicks on an image under the id 200 database shall not allow it to enter and gave him some error

Answer (score 3):

Sorry Had to see what your talking about.  Help to edit this so to understand your requirement, 'shall match that image to the value'

```
<input type="radio" name="image" class="100" value="a_100"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" class="100" value="b_100"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" class="100" value="c_100"/>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="100"/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="200"/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="300"/>

<?php

    $image = strstr($_POST['image'],'_'); 
    $number = '_'.$_POST['number'];

    if($image == $number) {
        //Do something
    }
```

Comment: So are your trying to match any of the first three images only to the first radio button with value of 100

Comment: well the answer is you can't.  PHP has no clue the id even exists

Comment: You'll have to incorporate the id into the value like @SDC said

Comment: can u show how can i do that (what sdc said) by updating the code in question??

Comment: The edits I made will  compare the image class to the number value.

Answer (score 0):

The question is looking for to compare the two fields in PHP. Presumably this means that you want to examine them when the form is posted.

This means that you'll only have available to you the parts of the field that are sent via the POST -- ie the field `name` and the `value`. PHP will never see the `id` of any of the fields, nor the `class`, nor any other attributes in the HTML code other than `name` and `value`.

Therefore the discussion in the comments about whether or not to use `id` is a somewhat moot point -- even if it is a good point for you to know in general for your HTML code, you can't really use either `id` or `class` here anyway because PHP will never see them.

You need to take an entirely different approach.

[EDITED after question edit]

Add the `100` or `200`, etc to the `value` of the `image` radio buttons, like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="image" value="a_100"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="b_100"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="c_100"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="d_200"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="e_200"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="f_300"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="g_300"/>
<input type="radio" name="image" value="h_400"/>
```

(The `number` radio button set remains unchanged from your question)

You can then read it in PHP as follows:

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
list($imgNumber, $imgValue) = explode('_',$_POST['image']);
```

You can now compare `$number` with `$imgNumber`.

Hope that helps.

It's worth asking a follow-up question though: What are you trying to achieve here? Is this a validation exersise? ie where you're checking that the user is selecting an `image` option that matches the `number` option he's picked? If that's what you're doing, you may find it's more user friendly to use Javascript to filter the options available when they select the `number` option so that the `image` radio button set only shows options that are valid for the selected `number`.

This would be an entirely different question, so I won't go into any detail here, but I would suggest that it might be a more user-friendly way of doing things if you did it like that.

Comment: buddy.. ive updated the question... now check.. and try to solve.. also.. i m ready to answer any question u'd like to... plz have a look

Comment: okay, so looking at the edits, your best option is to add the `100` or `200` etc to the `value`, as per the second option I gave you. I'll edit the answer to focus on that and how to read it in PHP.